# Magento 2.2.1 Error

Tags: error, magento2.2, admin-panel, server-setup

I got this error today out of no way, and i can't figure out how to solve it.

"A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later."

[image: Console Errors]

Comment: Any additional information? Did you customized something? You got this error when you did...

Comment: Please, check server log and magento exception and system log files.

Comment: Update:

 I realized i edited .htaccess to add a password to the website the password worked fine but i started receiving this error after that. 
My fault...

Comment: Please post your answer and set it as accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I realized i edited .htaccess to add a password to the website the password worked fine but i started receiving this error after that. My fault...